# preg_replace multiple strings between brackets (php/regex)

Tags: php, regex

I have string

```
[test](test\\-test\\-abc) abcde\\-
```

I would like to have

```
[test](test-test-abc) abcde\\-
```

I need to replace `\\-` with `-` with regex/preg_replace.
Need to replace string only between parenthesis. I found a solution but it only replaces first occurance.

```
$result = preg_replace("/(\[.*?\])(\(.*?)(\\\\-)(.*?\))/", '$1$2-$4', $str);
```

Comment: Those aren't brackets: those are parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$str = '[test](test\\\\-test\\\\-abc) abcde\\\\-';
$txt = preg_replace_callback('~\([^)]+\)~',
    function ($m) { return str_replace('\\\\-', '-', $m[0]); }, $str);
echo $txt;
//=> [test](test-test-abc) abcde\\-
```